# Vertical Thumbnails Gallery with auto play

Tags: jquery, scroll, gallery, thumbnails

I've made a photo gallery with vertical thumbnail, how can I emulate the mouse hover and click event on the thumbnail so that it animates automatically like you're clicking them..

Please take a look at the gallery I've done so far at http://misslebanon2010.com/urbana/new/index.php

If you can notice that you can scroll down and up you can also click on any thumbnails to show a bigger photo in the middle with description, the question is how can I make it play automatically

I've tried JCarousel Plugin but it's not playing it the way it has to be if you use it manually

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        //jCarousel Plugin
    $('#thumbs-carousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });

//Combine jCarousel with Image Display
$('#slideshow-carousel li a').hover(
    function () {

        if (!$(this).has('span').length) {
            $('#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({'border': '2px #ccc solid'});
            $(this).stop(true, true).children('img').css({'border':'2px orange solid'});
        }       
    },
    function () {

        $('#slideshow-carousel li a img').stop(true, true).css({'border': '2px #ccc solid'});
        $('#slideshow-carousel li a').each(function () {

            if ($(this).has('span').length) $(this).children('img').css({'border':'2px orange solid'});


        });

    }
).click(function () {

    $('span.arrow').remove();  
    $('#frtitle').html($(this).find("img").attr('title'));
    $('#desc').html($(this).find("img").attr('alt'));         
    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
    $('#slideshow-main li').removeClass('active');        
    $('#slideshow-main li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');  

    return false;
    });


});
    function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {

        // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
        carousel.clip.hover(function() {
            carousel.stopAuto();
        }, function() {
            carousel.startAuto();
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Yes I did but since my gallery has a bigger image next to thumbnails I need it to play automatically and scroll the thumbs and show corresponding big image of each thumb

Comment: i check your page source and i did not find jcarousel finction used..?? can you trace that code and post that in here...

Comment: Hey, I've attached the jCarousel code

Comment: HAI... PLEASE CROSS CHECK YOUR CODE PASTED HERE AND IN YOUR SITE HERE ITS PASTED AS $('#thumbs-carousel').jcarousel({ AND IN THE SITE ITS PASTED AS $('#carousel').jcarousel({ ??